# Stuck in sync process

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, cpp-ethereum, homestead, upgrading

- Node type: geth/eth
- OS: windows 64 bit
- Network type: main
- Mist version: 0.4.0 (trying to update to 0.5.2)

The problem is my mist wallet wont sync, i have taked a screenshot of Geth running and mist, do you have any idea why geth says "failed" i think that might is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you already figured out, you have to upgrade to mist 0.5.2 first.

The homestead fork was active at block 1,150,000 and only post-homestead releases like geth 1.3.5, eth 1.2.2, mist 0.5.2 will sync past that block.

So rather update now and sync later.

Comment: still thanks for the reply :-) I updated geth and it worked ! .-)